# dataTable text coloring by condition?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, datatable

How can I change the textcolor within a column by condition? eg

">=0 : green"

"<0 : red"

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

h:outputText value="something" style="#{someProperty >= 0 ? 'color: green' : 'color: red'}" />

In other words just make the condition in the el expression for the style. That's one way of doing it anyway.

Comment: Just for completeness sake, you could also use two outputTexts with fixed styles and use the rendered attribute to select which one to show. Pick your flavor. I prefer the first method. Cheers